# How to pass argument to a REST method

Tags: java, rest

I have created simple rest service @GET and takes 2 parameters username and password.
I m trying to search how to pass parameters through rest service client and how to get it using the method. I am unable to get the exact answer I want.

How can I pass parameters and how to use that in my webservice?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what framework you are using but if you use `Spring`, you can do it like this:

```
@Controller
public class SampleController {

@RequestMapping(value="/test/{name}/{password}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doTest(@PathVariable String name,@PathVariable String password, ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println("REST paras name:"+name+",password:"+password);
    return "samplePage";
}
}
```

then ,url path like  `[/test/{name}/info`] [`/test/{name}/info.*`]  [`/test/{name}/info/`] 
will pass to this method!

Answer (score 0):

You should look on something like:
`@HeaderParam` or `@PathParam`

in Jersey it looks like:

```
 @Get
    @Path("/mywebservice")
    public Response myWebService(@HeaderParam String username, 
                                 @HeaderParam String password)
    {
    ...
    }
```

but you should remember that this way of sending/receiving username and password isn't too secure ;)